# Using strcpy() to assign values to a struct. Program doesnt run

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am new to c and I'm trying to assign values to a struct using strcpy(I've tried to use assignment using lvalue method and that throws an error). I try to run the program and nothing happens. Where is the error in my code?
I'm using codeblocks to run the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    struct student{
        char name[25];
        int age;
    };
    struct student s1;
    strcpy(s1.name, "Sammy");
    strcpy(s1.age, "18");
    printf("%s, %d", s1.name, s1.age);
}
```

[image: The program doesn't run]

Comment: `s1.age` is an `int`, not a string.  You can't assign to it with `strcpy`.  Try `s1.age = 18;`.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Yes, now it seems to be working. Thanks for that

Comment: Also **#include <string.h>** some compilers might need it

Comment: s1.age=18 its not a string but int

Comment: if you do not get an error message for `strcpy(s1.age, "18");` then adjust your compiler settings -- you wasted a whole lot of time here that you could have saved by taking advantage of the compiler's diagnostics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to read the warnings from your compiler as they contain valuable information about problems with your code. Compiling the original code with gcc and clang gives these warnings:

clang:

> so5.c:12:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'char *' [-Wint-conversion]

gcc:

> so5.c:12:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>        strcpy(s1.age, "18");

So the offending line is:

```
strcpy(s1.age, "18");
```

is first treating the uninitiated s1.age as pointer and tries to copy the string into this unknown location. This will very likely result in a segmenation fault.

You could of course make a pointer of this and fill its memory contents with the `"18"`

```
strcpy(&s1.age, "18");
```

But wait this results in a print like:

> Sammy, 14385

Because the string is encoded in ascii, three bytes `0x31,0x38,0`

When written into the location of the `int age` field as `0x003831` or in decimal `14385`. This is however pure luck that the reaming byte(s) was randomly initiated to 0.

The correct way to assign age a value is with an assignment:

```
s1.age = 18;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
strcpy(s1.age, "18");
```

You can to normal assignment. `s1.age = 18;`

Comment: Yes, I've changed that, now it works. Thanks for that

Comment: Also, remove the strcpy for integer

Comment: @TruthSeeker Earlier it was &s...now question edited

Answer (score 0):

[strcpy()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) is used for copying strings to a character buffer. With `strcpy(s1.age, "18");`, you are trying to read something from the address of the string `18` and write to `s1.age` which is an `int`.

Either declare the `age` member to be a `char` array, just like you did for `name` (although this would restrict you from doing arithmetic operations on `age`). Or, use the assignment operator `=` to assign an `int`. Like: `s1.age = 18;`